# How to update progress from within a custom class

Tags: java, java-threads

I need to update the progress from a custom class inside a worker/task thread. How do I do this?

```
public Task createWorker() {
    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            DocumentProcessor dp = new DocumentProcessor();
            dp.proces(this);
        }

        public void notifyTask(String _msg, long _stepNumber, long _totalSteps ){
            updateMessage(_msg);
            updateProgress(_stepNumber, _totalSteps);
        }
    };
}
```

class:

```
public class DocumentProcessor {
    public void proces(Task _task){
         // Step 1
         _task.notifyTask("Step 1 done", 1 ,2); // ERROR: no function with that name

         // Step 2
         _task.notifyTask("Step 2 done", 2 ,2);

    }
}
```

invoke

```
    Task worker = createWorker();
    new Thread(worker).start();
```

The notifyTask function is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notifyTask` method is not available because it's not included in the `Task` class, but defined in your (anonymous) subclass.

You can for example create a named subclass and pass that to the `DocumentProcessor`.

```
public class NotifiableTask extends Task {
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        DocumentProcessor dp = new DocumentProcessor();
        dp.proces(this);
    }

    public void notifyTask(String _msg, long _stepNumber, long _totalSteps ){
       updateMessage(_msg);
       updateProgress(_stepNumber, _totalSteps);
   }
}
public Task createWorker() {
   return new NotifiableTask();
}

public class DocumentProcessor {
    public void proces(NotifiableTask _task){
       // Step 1
       _task.notifyTask("Step 1 done", 1 ,2); // function is now available because it's defined in NotifiableTask
       // Step 2
       _task.notifyTask("Step 2 done", 2 ,2);

    }
}

Task worker = createWorker();
new Thread(worker).start();
```

You can also define an interface and have your class implement that for looser coupling.

```
public interface Notifiable {
    void notifyTask(String _msg, long _stepNumber, long _totalSteps);
}

public class NotifiableTask extends Task implements Notifiable {
    // implement Task's call()
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        DocumentProcessor dp = new DocumentProcessor();
        dp.proces(this);
    }

    // implement Notifiable's notifyTask
    public void notifyTask(String _msg, long _stepNumber, long _totalSteps ){
       updateMessage(_msg);
       updateProgress(_stepNumber, _totalSteps);
   }
}
public Task createWorker() {
   return new NotifiableTask();
}

public class DocumentProcessor {
    // we don't need Task's call() method here, so pass the Notifiable only
    public void proces(Notifiable _task){
       // Step 1
       _task.notifyTask("Step 1 done", 1 ,2); // function is now available because it's declared in Notifiable
       // Step 2
       _task.notifyTask("Step 2 done", 2 ,2);

    }
}

Task worker = createWorker();
new Thread(worker).start();
```

You'll probably need to declare `NotifiableTask` as an inner class of wherever you currently define the `createTask` method because it needs to call its other methods (`updateMessage()` and `updateProgress()`) during `notifyTask()`. In fact, since the task itself only delegates this call, you might as well declare the interface in the outer class and perform the update there; but this depends on the context and is hard to tell since you obviously only provided a minimized example.